# AlertView with Checkbox Control in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to display an alert view dialog in ios with usual title, message and two buttons + additionally I need a check box  with message like "Always show this". In apple HIG document, they stated better to use an action sheet or view controller instead of displaying more controls in an alertview. Any alternative options are there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: www.cocoacontrols.com use and search

Comment: Visited... Got useful information and custom controls... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Custom View in which you can you all the required control and if you want to show the you can also use nice animation to show them and also you can set some good graphics as well. So the best way is to create CustomView.

All the best !!!